# Django 2, How to create an instance of Form in FormView with POST request?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form made with HTML and I'm using a formview to take advantage of the POST method. The form has information on several HTML related select (interactive with Javascript), so the best option for me was to create an HTML form.

In summary, I want to instance a form. A form with the POST information, process the form, return the error messages or save (save is not the problem).

Code

Form View

```
 class ServiceOrderForm(forms.Form):

        TYPE = (
            ('preventivo', 'Preventivo'),
            ('correctivo', 'Correctivo'),
            )

        STATUS = (
            ('abierta','Abierta'), #amarillo
            ('aprobada','Aprobada'), #verde
            ('modificada','Modificada'), #rojo
            ('realizada','Realizada'), #azul
            ('rechazada','Rechazada'), #naranja
            ('Cerrada','Cerrada'), #Azul con check
            )

        id_orden_servicio = forms.IntegerField()
        id_establecimiento = forms.IntegerField()
        id_equipo_establecimiento = forms.IntegerField()
        hora_entrada = forms.DateField()
        hora_salida = forms.DateField()
        tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE)
        id_tecnico = forms.IntegerField()
        fecha_panificada=  forms.DateField()
        hora_planificada = forms.DateField()
        fecha = forms.DateField()
        estado = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS)
        observaciones = forms.TextInput()
```

View

```
class ServiceOrderTemplateView(FormView):
    ''' Presenta el formulario del evento y sus detalles '''
    template_name = 'serviceorders/service-order.html'
    form_class = ServiceOrderForm

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        context = super(ServiceOrderTemplateView, self).get_context_data \
            (**kwargs)
        if request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_active:
            customer_group = CustomerGroupData(request.user.id).get()
            context_data_event = ContextDataEvent(customer_group)
            event_service = ServiceEvent(kwargs['id_order_service'])
            event_data = event_service.getEvent()

            estado_equipo = {
                'garantia': {
                    'label': 'danger',
                    'icon': 'fa-ban',
                },
                'vida_util' : {
                    'label': 'success',
                    'icon': 'fa-check',
                }
            }

            data = {
                'customer_group': customer_group,
                'establishments' : context_data_event.getEstablishments(),
                'equipments' : context_data_event.getEquipments(),
                'create': False,
                'technicals' : context_data_event.getTechnicals(),
                'current_equipment' : event_data['equipment'],
                'current_technical' : event_data['technical'],
                'current_establishment': event_data['establishment'],
                'current_year': 2018,
                'equipment_standard' : event_data['equipment_standard'],
                'historic_orders' : event_service.getHistoricEvent(),
                'current_order_detail' : event_service.getDetailService(),
                'images_service_order' : event_service.getImageItem(),
                'items_mantenimiento' : event_service.getDetailService(),
                'equipment_estatus' : estado_equipo,
                'order_service' : event_data['order_service'],
                'id_order' : kwargs['id_order_service'],
            }

            context.update({'data': data})

        return self.render_to_response(context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceOrderTemplateView, self).get_context_data \
            (**kwargs)

        form = ServiceOrderForm(request.POST)
        #the form always is empty

        #if form is valid this method return
        if form.is_valid():
            print('El formulario es valido')
            #more code
            HttpResponseRedirect('/mostrar/orden/servicio/')
        else:


            print('El formulario en invalido')
            #return this error ti html template
            print(form.errors)
        data = {
            'form': form,
            'errors' : form.errors
        }
        context.update({ 'data' : data })
        print('recibiendo data por post')

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

html

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
         {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" name="id_orden_servicio" value="{{ data.order_service.id_orden_servicio }}">
         <div class="col-md-1"></div>
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Nro Orden:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input
                  type="text"
                  readonly = ""
                  name="id_orden_servicio"
                  value="OS-{{ data.current_year }}-{{ data.order_service.id_orden_servicio }}"
                  >
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Establecimiento:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <select class="btn btn-sm btn-default" name="id_establecimiento" id="id_establecimiento">
                       {% if data.create == True %}
                             <option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>
                            {% for establishment in data.establishment %}
                                <option value="{{ establishment.id_establecimiento }}">{{ establishment }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                       {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ data.current_establishment.id_establecimiento }}" disabled selected>{{ data.current_establishment }}</option>
                       {% endif %}
                   </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Equipos:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="btn btn-sm btn-default" name="id_equipo_establecimiento" id="id_equipo_establecimiento">
                      {% if data.create == True %}
                             <option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>
                              {% for equipment in data.equipments %}
                                <option value="{{equipment.id_equipo_establecimiento}}">{{ equipment }}</option>
                              {%  endfor %}
                      {% else %}
                        <option value="{{data.current_equipment.id_equipo_establecimiento}}" disabled selected>{{ data.current_equipment }}</option>
                       {% endif %}
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Mantenimiento.:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="btn btn-sm btn-default" name="tipo_mantenimiento" id="tipo_mantenimiento">
                         {% if data.create == True %}
                             <option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>
                             <option value="preventivo">Preventivo</option>
                             <option value="correctivo">Correctivo</option>
                         {% else %}
                              <option selected disabled value="{{data.order_service.tipo}}">{{ data.order_service.tipo | upper}}</option>
                      {% endif %}
                     </option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Técnico:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="btn btn-sm btn-default" name="id_tecnico" id="id_tecnico">
                          {% if data.create == True %}
                             <option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>
                            {% for technical in data.technicals %}
                                <option value="{{technical.id_tecnico}}">{{ technicals.apellidos }} {{ technicals.nombres }} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                          {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ data.order_service.id_tecnico_id }}">{{ data.order_service.id_tecnico }}</option>
                          {% endif %}
                     </option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Fecha Mant.:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <input type="text" name="fecha" style="width: 100%" value = "{{ data.order_service.fecha | date:"d/m/Y"  }}">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Observaciones:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <textarea rows="5" cols="31" name="observaciones">{{ data.order_service.observaciones }}</textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Imagen de equipo:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <img src="{{BASE_URL}}media/{{ data.current_equipment.url_imagen }}" style="width: 60%;height: auto">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2 text-left">
                  <span class="label label-{{data.equipment_estatus.garantia.label}}">
                      <i class="fas {{ data.equipment_estatus.garantia.icon }}"></i> Garantía
                  </span>
                  <span class="label label-{{data.equipment_estatus.vida_util.label}}">
                      <i class="fas {{ data.equipment_estatus.vida_util.icon }}"></i> Vida Útil
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Plano ubicación:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <a href="{{BASE_URL}}media/{{ data.current_equipment.url_ubicacion}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" target="_blank">
                      <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Ver Ubicación
                  </a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Lugar:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" value="{{ data.current_equipment.ubicacion }}" readonly="">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Nro Serie:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" value="{{ data.current_equipment.nro_serie }}" readonly="">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <label>Estado Orden:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                   {% if data.create == True %}
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm {{data.order_service.estado}}">
                       <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                   ABIERTA
                   </a>
                   {% else %}
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm {{data.order_service.estado}}">
                       <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                       {{ data.order_service.estado | upper }}
                   </a>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">
                      {% if data.create == True %}
                      <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>
                      Agergar Orden Mantenimiento
                      {% else %}
                      <span class="fas fa-save"></span>
                      Guardar Cambios
                      {% endif %}
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   </form>
```

thanks!.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but wouldn't it be more suitable if you're going with a `CreateView` instead of a `FormView`?

Comment: I solved it

the form was always empty because the forms.py did not have the same fields as the html

i cant use createview because need add information in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

the form was always empty because the forms.py did not have the same fields as the html

i cant use createview because need add information in the form.